# locus of equation of straight lines?

Tags: geometry

Write down the equation of the locus of a point which moves in the xy plane
so that it is equidistant from the straight lines y = x and y = −x
[image]

from the digram i can conclude   that the  the  eqaution of locus of a points is triangle ...here i don't  know what will be equation of locus ?

Pliz help  and tell me the solution i would be grateful
thanks in advance

Comment: Lookup angle bisector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Won't the locus simply be the $x$ axis and $y$ axis respectively? Hence the locus would be $xy=0$

Comment: @ Manthanein,,im not getting

Comment: Well, it's a property that every point on x axis is equidistant from the lines y=x and y=-x.  The same goes for y axis.  You can prove this using the congruency of triangles

Comment: In your case you drew the diagram incorrectly because the equidistant in this case means that the perpendicular dropped from any point of desired locus on the given straight lines must be equal. But in your figure I don't see any perpendiculars dropped on the straight lines.

Comment: You are welcome